# What's causing 'cannot mkdir R_Temp'?

Tags: r

R was running perfectly on my machine until a data intensive neural network model was killed by the system. After that, I couldn't run R at all

```
$ R
Fatal error: cannot create 'R_TempDir'
```

So after viewing online resources, I first checked if the storage on /tmp was low, then checked the permissions for /tmp. Everything seems to be fine.

```
$ df /tmp
Use % - 13%

$ ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 22 root root 4096 Jan 23 16:23 /tmp
```

Comment: What OS version and R version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10, and R 4.3.1 "Beagle Scouts"

Comment: Do you have environment variables set with any of the names `TMPDIR`, `TMP` or `TEMP`? Do you have a `.Rprofile` file in your home directory?

Comment: No and no. I don't think not having it is causing the issue because my other system does not have them too and it works perfectly

Comment: Right. It's more than having them set might be causing the problem. Not having them set is the default. And R normally doesn't have a problem opening. Something is clearly awry with your setup. Hard to troubleshoot without being able to reproduce.

Comment: It had been working before. This whole issue occurred after a neural network model process was killed

Comment: if it's possible, have you tried a reboot? `sudo reboot`